Quickie - My index/match formula is not ignoring blanks
got this formula to indirectly list unique values (independently from the original list). it is adapted from Google to suit my needs and it works but is listing the blank cell as a 0. please help.
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$C$3&"'!B3:B500"), MATCH(0,COUNTIF($I$2:I2, INDIRECT("'"&$C$3&"'!B3:B500")), 0)), "")
Thanks in advance
